# What is a term for "fear of very large enclosed spaces"?

Tags: single-word-requests, psychology, phobias

I'm intrigued by a hybrid of "agoraphobia" (which would be more accurately referred to as "kenophobia") and "claustrophobia," described by [H. P. Lovecraft like this](https://github.com/punchmonster/Lovecraft-Letters/blob/master/19370299-Harry-O-Fischer.md):

> Of the celebrated "phobias" of the modern psychologists (or of things like them) I have only *one*; & that, amusingly enough, is one I have never seen cited or named. Probably it *has* a name & record, but my very superficial knowledge of psychology (a subject which fails to fascinate me greatly, despite its grotesque fictional possibilities) does not include any glimpse of it. I know about *claustrophobia* & *agoraphobia*, but I have neither. I have, however, a *cross betwixt the two*—in the form of **a distinct fear of *very large enclosed spaces*.** The dark carriage-room of a stable—the shadowy interior of a deserted gas-house—an empty assembly-room or theatre-auditorium—a large cave—you can probably get the idea.

So, is there a word for this? A word ending in -phobia that means "fear of very large enclosed spaces"?

Comment: Wasn't Lovecraft all about nameless dreads?

Comment: This seems akin to a request about what to call the shortest giant in the world.

Comment: I would have coined _atriophobia_ from Latin [_atrium_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atrium_(architecture)) akin to _claustrophobia_ from Latin _claustrum_.

Comment: Agoraphobia *isn't* actually a fear of wide open spaces *per se*; see [this article from the Mayo Clinic.](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/agoraphobia/symptoms-causes/syc-20355987)

Answer (score 0):

There is no authentic scientific term for this as yet. It certainly cannot be labeled (the seemingly similar phobia-) Altocelarophobia, which is a fear specifically of high ceilings:

> [A fear of high ceilings, also known as altocelarophobia, is far more common than we would first expect and many people say that they feel insignificant in such a place or that they are going to float up and away.](https://hypnoticworld.com/hypnosis-scripts/fears-phobias/altocelarophobia-fear-of-high-ceilings)

The phobic sensation- the fear of floating away- would be unique to a high ceiling and thus could not apply to a general fear of large places.

Answer (score -2):

Altocelarophobia is the fear of tall ceilings, and large enclosed rooms. It's latin roots are alto (high) and (i think) caelum, which is sky (or ceiling)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Usually phobias use Greek roots. Surely Greek has words for high ceilings.

Comment: ...claustrophobia notwithstanding

Comment: @siride Not so according to the [British NHS](https://www.nhs.uk/mental-health/conditions/claustrophobia/) which defines it as "an irrational fear of _confined_ spaces" which the OP says they do not suffer from. A large enclosed space is not a confined space although it may contain confined spaces, a  large railway station will contain lifts, toilets, train carriages and small offices but there is little or no constraint on the movement of a person in the wider space. It is closer to agorophobia but the space is not open. It genuinely is a third condition in my opinion.

Comment: @BoldBen I was just talking about roots.

Comment: @siride I beg your pardon.